# Does one have the freedom to impose a Euclidean metric in each finite dimensional representation of a finite dimensional semi-simple Lie Algebra?

Tags: metric-tensor, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437501/trace-of-generators-of-lie-group) similar post led me to this question. In the adjoint representation, I can construct the killing form to act as a metric on the elements in the algebra. It is often convenient to choose a basis so the metric (killing form) is the identity $\delta_{ij}$.

My question is if this choice enforces or induces a metric on any or all of the other representations (such as scaling by the dynkin index perhaps?), or if I am able to get away with having the identity metric in each representation.

Comment: If the metric is supposed to be invariant $g([x,y],z)=g(x,[y,z])$ it already fails for the real Lie algebra $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Is that a comment about real forms? In the complexified Lie algebra, you can choose a basis which leads to the identity metric for any representation.

Comment: @Qmechanic what if I restrict myself to compact Real forms

Comment: @Craig : Then it works.